# All display managers boot into Gnome Classic (No effects)

Tags: gnome, lightdm, gnome-classic, gdm

I've tried both `gdm` and `lightgdm` but no matter what I do, I get logged in to Gnome Classic (No Effects). The terminal's transparency is a nuisance here and I completely do not want to work on anything until things start looking pretty again.

I just want to be able to use the proper Gnome shell when I select it.

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments/162518#162518), help?

Comment: No, @Mitch. That is exactly my question. No matter what I select, I am only served with the no effects shell.

Answer (score 1):

The issue wasn't with the display managers but with gnome itself. I completely uninstalled `gnome-shell` and then logged in. I had lost both Unity and Gnome and wasn't able to use the computer.

I installed Gnome again via the tty terminal  (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and now I'm working in the pretty environment again.