# How to have a clean *ubuntu and Awesome WM?

Tags: awesome

My request is quite simple. How can I get a *buntu distro but with [awesome](https://awesomewm.org/) in it? How can I wipe off everything in Ubuntu (Unity & stuff) and get awesome WM?

What I'd like is *buntu ease of use + awesome WM.

Ideas on how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would advise you to go with Xubuntu (last LTS or latest).

1. Install [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/)
2. Install awesome

   ```
   sudo apt-get install awesome awesome-extra
   ```

   If you want the most updated version, run before:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:klaus-vormweg/awesome
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Remove Xubuntu desktop.

   If you don't remove these package, it will override the awesome background and can conflict with apps if you don't set specific awesome rules.

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove  xubuntu-desktop xfdesktop4
   ```
4. Set awesome as the default WM

   ```
   sudo xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /sessions/Failsafe/Client0_Command -t string -s "awesome" -a
   ```
5. Set awesome to autostart

   ```
   ln -s /usr/share/applications/awesome.desktop ~/.config/autostart/awesome.desktop
   ```
6. Restart lightdm service

   ```
   sudo service lightdm restart
   ```

With this configuration, you have a lightweight, updated and fast Ubuntu Awesome. To help you customize Awesome, I would advise you to look at the [awesome-copycats](https://github.com/copycat-killer/awesome-copycats).

Comment: Why is xubuntu preferred? Is there some aspect of it that is better than lubuntu for AwesomeWM?

Answer (score 1):

I install Awesome WM on top of Ubuntu server edition, this is certainly not a "simple" route, but you get a "clean" Awesome install.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one of the derivatives? You can choose for GNOME, KDE, Xfce etc.

http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives

You can also install ubuntu and then install another WM like GNOME:

[Switching window manager/desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments)

Comment: If it were that simple, my friend, I'd go for it. I couldn't find a Ubuntu Awesome edition. Plus, if there was one, I bet it's outdated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Awesomebuntu" distro, but you can simply install the Awesome WM package and either [configure GNOME for Awesome WM](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quickly_Setting_up_Awesome_with_Gnome#Gnome_3.9_.2F_Ubuntu_13.10) or get a [display manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager) which gets out of your way, such as [SLiM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_manager#Incompatibility_with_systemd).

That said, I personally found [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide) to be a much more rewarding platform once the (admittedly time consuming) [Awesome RC](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.config/awesome/rc.lua), [XTerm](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.Xresources) and [X setup](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.xinitrc) was over.

Comment: Time is the very factor that made me go to ubuntu.

Comment: All the graphics issues and lack of support for non-Unity desktops drove me to Arch, which has probably saved me time in the long run.