# How do i switch to Unity from Xmonad

Tags: unity, xmonad

Im a real noob with computers and installed accidentally Xmonad, without knowning that it was code-based. How can i switch back to unity?

Comment: crtl + alt + t didnt worked. It did nothing, showed a bunch of numbers and codes and disappeared. I did a bunch of times tho. And than once it opened GRUB. Didnt know what to do there so i turned of. crtl + alt + f1 made me enter and do the login. Then i wrote what you said and this appeared:

WARNING, no display variable set, setting it to:

...

didnt tried the other imperfect way. Why is imperfect, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

Two imperfect ways to do this:

(Assuming Unity is still installed)

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to open up a terminal, and type:

  unity --replace

or

- Log out of your account, and do this [Switching window manager/desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments)

Answer (score 0):

Use CTRL + ALT + F1 like you did before and login with your username and password.

Then type this:

```
sudo apt-get purge xmonad && sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

When that's said and done with, you can start a regular xsession with this command:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

or

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

To bypass the login screen and go directly into your default desktop type:

```
startx
```

To see if there are any other related packages still installed you can type this command:

```
dpkg -l | grep xmonad
```

No output = no packages are installed.