# KDE power management could not be initialized on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, kde

I am using Virtualbox and I have Kubuntu as my first virtual machine,

I was doing an upgrade (apt-get upgrade) when I suddenly closed my VM by mistake

No the problem is that I can no longer go past the log screen (where I write my password) because the screen become black and it says :

```
KDE power management could not be initialized on virtualbox
```

I am very new to Kubuntu but I know for a fact that it is because I stopped the upgrade,

Is there a way to keep this VM? or I have to start a new one? because I have a very important project on it due for tomorrow and I don't want to work all night to redo it!

Comment: First off, please calm down. Edit the title to be more appropriate and remove the "PLEASE COMMUNITY..." and past. Welcome to AskUbuntu, by the way!

Comment: Second, you can pull important files off of a "crippled" machine. But, that's a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, I would install an entirely different desktop manager, since the problem is apparently with KDE, and use that for 24 hours, and then fix the actual problem tomorrow.

You may already have one. Click the little ubuntu logo next to your login on the login window (it might be something else on kubuntu, have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments) to get an idea), and select one that isn't KDE.

If KDE is your only option, you can install a different desktop easily:

edit: consider first cloning your KDE install from virtual box, and then attempting this. That way you can always backtrack to your current state.

Press ctrl-alt-f1 to get to a terminal, and log in using your normal credentials.

Type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, and let it do it's thing to install the unity desktop.

Once it's done `sudo reboot` and wait for it to get back to the login page. Then, click the little ubuntu logo (or whatever it is), select the unity desktop and log in.

Comment: There are smaller packages too, `openbox` (a meg or 2?), `xfwm4` (xfce window manager), ... the whole `lxde` with it's apps looks to be about 25MB. `ubuntu-desktop` wants to add 125MB (to an xfce install)