# XBMC takes over my account at login

Tags: boot, xbmc

At login in when I enter my password, "XBMC" pops up instead. prior to that ubuntu was not accepting my password at all.  it would not say it was incorrect, just return to login. It would allow me to enter as a guest. I was having various minor problems before this. I have sent crash reports and asked for fixes etc.

Comment: 1. _When_ or _after_ you enter your password (in case it's when, how many characters can you type into the password field?)? 2. "enter as a guest" ?= "login as guest"? 3. Links to reports, please!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've changed your desktop session to XBMC.

Log out (via XBMC's power menu), or the <kbd>S</kbd> key) and then [pick another session type at the login screen](https://askubuntu.com/a/400581/449).