# Wily Werewolf: Install MATE DE additional to Unity

Tags: unity, 15.10, mate

Dear ubuntu community,

I just upgraded a freshly installed ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 (wily werewolf) and installed additionally the MATE desktop environment using the following command as described in [this article](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/MATE/):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

Everything seemed to work: After boot I see the MATE login screen but after login Unity is loaded. Even after removing MATE desktop again, the login screen stays MATE-style.

Is it even possible to install MATE additionally to Unity and choose between these two at login time?
Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching window manager/desktop environments?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made it in reverse:
First installed ubuntu MATE freshly, then installed Unity additionally via:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This seems to work. So if you aim to install MATE and Unity alongside, I'd recommend to do it this way. ;)

Comment: you may have more than one desktop enviroment installed and you may select the desired one at the login screen by clicking on the ubuntu icon next to the user selection