# Removing all other window manager/desktop environments?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

Based on [Switching window manager/desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/q/162516/80483), I installed gnome-desktop and lubuntu-desktop &c, but now I want to get rid of this bloat and just keep ubuntu-desktop.

What do I need to do to remove the desktop environment icon next to the user name from the login screen??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of this bloat and just keep ubuntu-desktop try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(lubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Comment: Looks radical! However, the `aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(lubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'` command suggested removing `bzr`, `gimp` and 600+ other packages, which is definitely not what I had in mind.

Comment: It is that all packets that are not default in Ubuntu are removed.