# Switch from UbuntuGNOME to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, 16.10

How to change my UbuntuGNOME to Ubuntu? 
I have faced incompatibility issues when using Teamviewer. So decided to go back for pure Ubuntu version with Unity. At the moment I am using 16.10 UbuntuGNOME. Is the best way to get Ubuntu 16.10 to use fresh install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu GNOME is an official Ubuntu flavour, which means the operating system is all Ubuntu and only the desktop environment has been changed from Unity to GNOME.

Thus all you need to do is install Unity, log out, select Unity as your desktop environment and log back in.

Install Unity via

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

or via the software center.

Comment: Do I have to uninstall my gnome?

Comment: No, you can keep both. Think of the DE as a program that is only being run when you actually start it, e.g. installing and using Chrome as your browser does not mean you need to uninstall Firefox. You might be asked if you want to switch display managers (i.e. the program that shows you your login screen and where you can change your desktop environment) - it is save to use either `gdm` or `lightdm` on any other. You can also switch anytime later.

Comment: But if i wish, how to uninstall it fully?

Comment: Uninstalling a DE can sometimes be a hassle as there might be shared libraries with Unity or other programs - Nevertheless this is a completely separate question and actually has some good answers on askubuntu already. Just search for `uninstall gnome`.

Comment: I tried your commands, but I still get GNOME DE, only login page is Unity.

Comment: So the installation went fine, I assume. Did you also pick Unity instead of GNOME before login? Otherwise it'll take the previous one. Click the Ubuntu logo right above where you put in your login credentials (see pictures in jamesc's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments))