# Standard UI For Studio?

Tags: software-center, gui, ubuntu-studio

Is there any way to change the UI for Ubuntu Studio to the standard one?

To illustrate what I mean by the "standard" one:

I've got 3 problems that are conspiring to make my Ubuntu Studio system virtually unusable:

1. There is an outstanding bug with WiFi that occasionally disconnects
   me from the Internet and the only way to get it back is reboot.
2. There is an outstanding bug with Ubuntu shutdown that causes it to
   hang.
3. If one presses the reset button or pull the plug to reboot it leaves
   the system in a state where, upon boot, it causes the startup of
   programs to fail so the system is only partially working:  Dual
   monitor comes up single monitor (mirrored), most of the startup   programs (Skype, Dropbox, etc.) aren't running and sometimes the net won't
   restart.  Only repeatedly rebooting will get things back to "normal"
   -- usual 2 or 3 reboots.  Fortunately those reboots don't hang.

Trying to find out workarounds for all of these problems inevitably takes me to posts on askubuntu.com with directions like this:

> Go to your System Settings->Software and Updates->Developer Options
>   tab click the box next to Pre-release (xenial-proposed). enter your
>   root pwd, Refresh the cache. Updates tab use "display updates
>   immediately drop down" close System Settings. Start software updater
>   and install now.

Yes, I can usually figure out what that means in terms of the Studio UI but it frequently takes hours of work.

I'd rather ditch the Studio UI and have something that is "standard" so I can get work done.

Comment: Install the `ubuntu-desktop` package

Answer (score 2):

## Change just the UI

1. Remove the `ubuntustudio-desktop` package by `apt purge ubuntustudio-desktop`.
2. Install the `ubuntu-desktop` package.
3. You can now select the desktop you want to log into from the login screen, see: [Switching window manager/desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments)

You know have the 'standard' Ubuntu UI.

## Change the whole OS

1. Download Ubuntu 16.04.1 from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.
2. Install it (as you did for the Studio version)
3. Now install any applications you might need (every multimedia application in Studio is available in all versions).

Comment: Are you sure removing `ubuntu-studio-package` will remove desktop related package? If it is a metapackage then this wont remove

Comment: The package name is `ubuntustudio-desktop`

```apt remove ubuntustudio-desktop
apt install ubuntu-desktop```

It didn't seem to change anything but one of the icons in the notifcation area.

Comment: @Anwar Corrected, had to `purge`.

Comment: @JamesBowery Annswer edited, try again