# Can't switch between Gnome and Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: gnome

I installed Ubuntu GNOME On my PC and i switched to it but now i want to switch back to the normal desktop every time i click the little foot logo it just shows a bar can't login nothing i have to force restart my PC

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/400581/518562

Comment: it doesn't let me do that as i said when i press the foot logo i only get a blank bar and i cant click anything

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you are describing please?

Comment: i cant if i turn off my PC and try to switch the foot thing i see nothing but a blank shade thing

Comment: Can you take a picture with your phone camera then?

Comment: i don't have a phone anymore how can i explain it

Comment: let me try to put it simply : When i turn on my PC i have the login screen then i have the Foot in the login box and when i click it i get the box but wth nothing on it i cant do anything else then i have to restart my PC and use this GNOME desktop

Comment: Did you do something previously to installing Gnome Shell?

Comment: nope atleast i don't think so