# KDE connect indicator not opening for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, kde-connect

I'm not able to access or open KDE connect indicator. 
Whereas kde connect monitor and kde connect settings are opening. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have both the following packages installed? `kdeconnect`, `indicator-kdeconnect`? On a terminal run `dpkg -l  indicator-kdeconnect kdeconnect` and tell us what two letters are written on the left of their names in the output. For example, if installed the letters should be "ii".

Comment: Yeah they are installed

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get purge indicator-kdeconnect`, `sudo apt-get purge kdeconnect`. Log out, log in. Re-install both from synaptic package manager or by running `sudo apt-get install kdeconnect indicator-kdeconnect`. Tell us if this helps.

Comment: When I installed `indicator-kdeconnect` I noticed that it didn't show up in the system tray till I restarted the computer and re-opened the indicator applet. So if the above doesn't work, try this too.

Comment: I checked the first one and found the output ii ; and              dkpg-query: no packages found matching indicator-kdeconnect

Comment: You don't have the proper repo added to your system to install the indicator. See my answer below.

Comment: I'm able to send text; urls ; files from my mobile to pc but the reverse is not possible.(pc to mobile) Possibly i didn't find a share option?

Comment: Just curious here, what version Linux (kernel, distro, release) are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ; I'm having a little confusing when i search for kde , found 3 - settings indicator and monitor ; was able to configure settings & view monitor ;  does the indicator usually open?

Comment: Did you follow the steps in my answer?

Comment: Yeah ! Just checked again but the indicator isn't opening .

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try unpair and start over, but make sure you request pair from the desktop app to the phone and not the other way around.

Also, verify that the phone is:

- On
- Connected to same WiFi as your Ubuntu device.

Otherwise, there could be something wrong. In this case you can consider reinstalling `kde-connect` as suggested by [@ThisIsNotAnId](https://askubuntu.com/users/45639/thisisnotanid):

```
sudo apt purge indicator-kdeconnect kdeconnect
sudo apt install indicator-kdeconnect kdeconnect
```

Comment: Ah... I'm missing the point.

Comment: Tried unpair and re connecting & reinstall but  the same only kdeconnect settings and kdeconnect monitor are opening.  Kdeconnect indicator keeps closing even before start.

Comment: The steps you mentioned about pairing are important. I think I noticed the same problem running the kdeconnect the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Following our discussion in the comments, it seems you don't have the necessary repo on your system for `indicator-kdeconnect`. Run the following on a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vikoadi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-kdeconnect
```

Log out, log in. Open indicator applet.

===**EDIT**===

Open a terminal and run `indicator-kdeconnect` and post any messages, errors, warnings that the terminal gives in your question.

Comment: No luck.  Not opening. Tried exactly the same commands and procedure.

Comment: @user648595 I think there may be broken packages on your system. I'm not sure what the problem might be. It could be the DE you're using. I don't know what environments other than unity 16.04 ships with. But if you have another DE installed can you login to that environment and try opening again? If you don't know how to change the DE look at this answer and see if you have something similar: http://askubuntu.com/a/400581/45639  If this doesn't work out, you might want to consider asking a question here about unity, installing another DE (try Budgie), or re-installing unity (not recommended).