# Come back to Ubuntu from Xubuntu

Tags: 14.04, unity, xubuntu

Here is my problem:
I was on Ubuntu LTS 16.04. I then moved to Xubuntu. However I really want to come back to Ubuntu. This is why I reboot my computer with an usb key with Ubuntu inside.

However I still have the Xubuntu desktop and menu but when I press CTRL ALT F1, it tells me that I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

If someone knows how to come back to "real" ubuntu, i would be very thankful!

Thank you

Comment: I think this answer should help:  https://askubuntu.com/a/400581/231142

Comment: Are you trying to reinstall Ubuntu entirely (replacing Xubuntu with Ubuntu and erasing all your files in the process), or install Unity on your current installation of Xubuntu? Since you have a "usb key with Ubuntu inside", I am assuming it contains the Ubuntu installation media? If so, you can replace Xubuntu with Ubuntu by booting from the USB device and installing using the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option (it will obviously erase everything so have all files backed up). [Basically, just install Ubuntu over Xubuntu.](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Hey! 

Thank you for your answer. I therefore boot ubuntu with my bootable key. However I have this message when launching the installation: 

"erro: file '/casper/vmlinuz.efi' not foud. alloc magic is broken at 0x72436500: 722402e0 Aborted. press any key to exit.

I boot my key via unetbootin.

Comment: And indeed, when I go in the file capser there are no vmlinuz file. Only 4 files : filesystem.manifest .