# How to switch desktop manager from LXDE?

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, desktop-environments, lxde, lxqt

So, the thing is, I wanted to try LxQT desktop manager. So I've installed `lxqt` package, but now I don't know, how to switch to LxQT from the current LXDE.

I tried to look for it, but I've only found some info about Unity and XFCE, like in this question:
[Switching window manager/desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments)

But, when I log out, I don't see any icon next to the user-name, that I could click-on, or some arrow, like in XFCE...

So, what can I do, to switch to the other desktop manager in LXDE?

---

#### EDIT

My login screen looks exactly like this (but this image is not mine)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to click on the small bird icon to the left of "en_US" in the top panel.
This should give a drop down list of available desktops.

Comment: Could you, please, add a screenshot, so it would be better visible?

Comment: Look at the top right hand corner of the screenshot that you have supplied. There is a small round icon to the left of "en_US". Click on it and see what desktops are available.