# Ubuntu 18 - Switching window manager

Tags: gnome, 18.04, awesome

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, and want to try the Awesome window manager. I installed it with `sudo apt install awesome`. How can I switch between GNOME and Awesome?

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments), but I can't see how to "log out, choose the one you want, and log back in." under GNOME.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When on the logon page, next to the "Sign In" button, a little [cogwheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FtxL.jpg) should be visible, showing the various options for window manager. I wasn't getting any new options beyond "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu on Wayland".

Eventually I found out I needed to restart the computer before it gave me the option to log on with Awesome.

Comment: i note that this does NOT work for the window manager part of compiz... it never shows up even after a reboot!