# TigerVNC config with Ubuntu 20.04, black screen

Tags: gnome, 20.04, vnc

I installed **TightVNC** on a **Ubuntu20.04*** machine in order to use it remotely from my macbook pro.
I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04-quickstart),

And it works with the **fce4 desktop**.
However I have a **black screen** whenever I try to use the **gnome desktop** with it:
I tried to change the config follwing [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285420/how-to-properly-configure-xstartup-file-for-tightvnc-with-ubuntu-20-04-lts-gnome), but nothing seems to work.

Here is **~/.vnc/xstartup**

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:GNOME"
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"


[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-session --builtin --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

my **/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service**

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=Start TightVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ben
Group=ben
WorkingDirectory=/home/ben

PIDFile=/home/ben/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 -localhost :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the service file **/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service**

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=Start TightVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ben
Group=ben
WorkingDirectory=/home/ben

PIDFile=/home/ben/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 -localhost :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `sudo systemctl status vncserver@1` command returns:

```bsh
● vncserver@1.service - Start TightVNC server at startup
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2021-02-22 12:26:43 CET; 4min 53s ago
    Process: 11916 ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1235 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 22 12:01:51 ben-monster gnome-session-binary[1305]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Feb 22 12:01:51 ben-monster gnome-session-b[1305]: unable to create file '/home/ben/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
Feb 22 12:01:51 ben-monster gnome-session[1305]: gnome-session-binary[1305]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Feb 22 12:01:51 ben-monster gnome-session-binary[1305]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Feb 22 12:01:51 ben-monster gnome-session-binary[1305]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Feb 22 12:01:51 machine-name gnome-session-binary[1305]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Feb 22 12:26:43 machine-name org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1913]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Feb 22 12:26:43 machine-name vncserver[11916]: Killing Xtigervnc process ID 1235... which was already dead
Feb 22 12:26:43 machine-name vncserver[11916]: Cleaning stale pidfile '/home/ben/.vnc/machine-name:1.pid'!
Feb 22 12:26:43 machine-name systemd[1]: vncserver@1.service: Succeeded.
```

Furthermore, I Have the error message on my blackscreen:

**Could not update ICEAuthority file /run/-/user//-ICEAuthority**

It is probably a config or a rights error, but after two days of playing around, I am starting to lose faith.

Comment: Note that the line ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1 has a illegal minus symbol before /usr/bin. Also, make sure everything inside /home/ben folder is accessible to the user ben. type: man chown for details.

Comment: " ~/.vnc/xstartup is no longer supported." as mentioined in https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/pull/838#issue-448100263 reference to it was used to close issue thread "TigerVNC server only getting black screen on connect #684"
https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/issues/684

Answer (score 1):

I just followed your configuration with few changes and I think I got what your want in the end:

[image]

. My changes were:

I fixed the line:

```
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
```

by

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
```

whitout the '-' character before `/usr/bin`

In addition to this, I changed the references to the name of the user from 'ben' to my user in:

```
User=ben
Group=ben
WorkingDirectory=/home/ben

PIDFile=/home/ben/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
```

Thus, my file ended up as:

```
User=my_user
Group=my_user
WorkingDirectory=/home/my_user

PIDFile=/home/my_user/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
```

Assuming that your user actually is `ben`, I think you have some files with limited permitions on `/home/ben` home folder. You can check [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/35076/need-to-fix-file-permissions-in-a-users-home-directory) for details about fix it. Maybe you need to give the ownership of files in this directory to the user ben using the command `chown` or just change the permition using `chmod`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it with uncommenting
"WaylandEnable=false" from /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

Then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak # this file may not exist so if there is an error, it can be ignored
sudo cp /etc/X11/vncserver-virtual-dummy.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Note: Following these steps will result in any connected monitors displaying a blank screen. If you need to use a monitor, run sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.dummy and reboot

https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005081572-Display-issues-when-connecting-to-VNC-Server-running-on-Linux