# Google account login on a headless system?

Tags: 20.04, google-drive

I have a machine that is going to be put into a 'remote desktop center' to accommodate a WFH model. The system is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for reasons left to another discussion.
An issue I cannot figure out how to overcome is logging into my corporate Google account and mounting my Google drive.
I was using a PiKVM I personally owned to use the local desktop to sign in via gnome-online-accounts (GOA).
But the PiKVM isn't an option now. Because Vino has problems running headless and working at all without first doing something at the local desktop, it's not an option.

I've tried a couple VNC solutions. Anything that sets up XFCE seems to be a no-go because there isn't a way to use GOA.
I got *really* close using [this askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285420/how-to-properly-configure-xstartup-file-for-tightvnc-with-ubuntu-20-04-lts-gnome) and while GOA seemed to try, it never managed to actually log in. I suspect its a keyring issue but I couldn't figure out how get the keyring app to run in the VNC xwindows session.

At this point I'm kind of over this cycle of trying a remote solution, fighting with it, having it fail, then trying to move on to the next one.

I need a way that I can log into my company's Google services via the SSO infrastructure, and map a folder on my google drive to the Linux system. If it's a remote solution that will work, that's fine. If it's a command line solution that works via SSH, that is also fine.