# I need help to correctly install Ubuntu in an Old Laptop

Tags: system-installation

I am not sure if I did this correctly but downloaded Ubuntu, but not sure if it is the right one.

I'm using a Dell Inspiron duo 1090 an old lap top that I believe is nine years old!

It has been converted to Windows 10 BUT is super slow!!!

I have used Ubuntu before at Amazon in Cape Town and it was great and quick and very user friendly!!

Can somebody please, kindly tell me how can I install Ubuntu in this old computer?

I bought from e-bay about a month ago.

I though am not a PC whiz and haven't a clue what to do?

Comment: And [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: If I have read the specification details correctly, this computer can manage 64-bit operating systems, but it is not very powerful. I would recommend that you try the *light-weight* Ubuntu family flavours Lubuntu or Xubuntu from http://releases.ubuntu.com/ - version 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Laptop specifications ([see here](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-Inspiron-Duo-1090.55017.0.html)) you will need an older Ubuntu version to make it work as fast as you expect.

I have two HP Mini 1000, whose specifications can be reached [clicking here](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01683469.pdf), and they suffer when I try to run Ubuntu 20.04, nevertheless, the processor and 2GB RAM is enough to do something with Ubuntu 18.04, which will be supported until April 2021.

Please have in consideration that your computer has a 1.5 GHz microprocessor and my HP Mini 1000 has the 1.6 GHz microprocessor.

While this shouldn't represent a major issue, you may find a slow performance with such difference.

And please have in consideration that you can't use the Ubuntu's official Desktop Environment.

In my Mini 1000 I am using i3WM, but you can go for [XFCE Desktop Environment](https://www.xfce.org/), then you will experience some king of additional speed on the computer's general performance.

Or you should go directly to download the [XUbuntu distribution](https://xubuntu.org/), which is a Ubuntu's derivative OS

The [Official XUbuntu Documentation](https://docs.xubuntu.org/1804/user/C/index.html) has enough information on how to install it, nevertheless you may wish to give this task to a computer's expert.

But, if you insist on do it on your own, you will need to learn some things.

People in the comments have dropped useful links on how to install Ubuntu, the XUbuntu installation process is not that different, so you will be covered by following these instructions.

### Computer's comparison

You can see the differences between your computer and my Mini 1000 by [clicking here](https://www.notebookcheck.net/index.php?id=127065&specs%5B%5D=11029&specs%5B%5D=3870).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! I must though admit that I was hoping for a simple download and activation nothing too drastic or technical and that may take a while to do? Yes not just a quick and easy one but something that is pretty plain and straight and not to over involved?

Comment: This link (https://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2018/08/29/beginners-guide-how-to-install-ubuntu-linux/#4551fad951c9) has a comprehensive guide to install Ubuntu 18.04, the most difficult part on this guide is the creation of the Installation/Bootable USB. You must find a way to gather it, and if somebody is going to help you, please ask her/him to get an XUbuntu Installation USB. The same guide provides a way to do it with ease.

Comment: But if you can't get the XUbuntu USB, just go for the regular Ubuntu Installation USB, some donuts and a coffe, lots of patience and run the process. You will get the computer booting with Ubuntu in a couple of hours, after which you will need to open a terminal with <key>CTRL</key>+<key>ALT</key>+<key>T</key> and run `sudo tasksel install xubuntu-desktop`, then just follow this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/400581/9598 to change the default Desktop Environment.

Comment: Please let us know if you succeeded and don't hesitate to drop a new question if you need further assistance. But please, don't forget to run a search first. Some of your questions may already have answers here. Good luck!